# Twitter Widget profile script outputting white screen?

Tags: panels, social-network

Does anyone know why I'm receiving a white screen when I added the following code into a page panel?

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#4aed05'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('Twitter').start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used the twitter widgets in blocks almost exactly (eg, different theme settings and users) like the above, and shoving a cut and paste of your code above works fine in a static .htm, so, I'd check your php and other console/error logs to see what drupal is upset about. First idea is an input filter is bolloxing it up.